# Dynamically call images from a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, image

Im trying to make simple website ( images , buttons, forms etc) and i have many images but i dont want to set their URL one by one ,instead i want to make something like this

For example i have 3 images image1,image2,image3 already created so in HTML

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1"
<asp:Image ID="Image2"
<asp:Image ID="Image3"
enter code here
```

I have a folder with images which names are 1,2, ... ,5,6,... 
and on Page_Load event i want to call them like that

```
for (int i=1; i< 4;i++){
image[i].ImageUrl = "(path of the folder)"+i.ToString()+".jpg";
}
```

What is the best way to do this

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? I can see some obvious improvements but I think that's pretty much the idea.

Comment: Well image[i] is not a valid variable it just does not compile or maybe i dont know the syntax

Comment: you need some sort of imagecontainer (`asp:Panel`) which is known serverside and just add `new HtmlImage()` to this container.

Comment: @spirit_seller I see. I think the provided answer will solve that problem for you then. On a side note you should provide a bit more detail in your question because for all I know `image` is of type `List<Control>` and is already populated. If that were the case your code would run as intended. Always good to include error info, what line causes it and all necessary details about the variables in your code.

Comment: i have posted an answer with the error info

Answer (score 1):

You're nearly there - Use `FindControl` to find each Image control

```
for (int i=1; i< 4;i++)
{
    Control control = Page.FindControl(string.Format("Image{0}", i));
    if (control != null)
    {
        control.ImageUrl = "(path of the folder)"+i.ToString()+".jpg";
    }
}
```

As @efkah points out, if you put these image controls in a panel it'll be faster to find them using `MyPanel.FindControl(...`

Comment: y these images are in a panel id="panel1"